# Loop until the user enters his birthday in the correct format

Tags: ruby

I wat [sic] the user to comply to the format (`dd.mm.yyyy`). I want to repeatadly ask the user for his birthday until he enters his birthday in the correct format. How would I make the question for user input loop until the user enters his birthday in the correct format? Which conditions can I set for the user input?

This is the small program I am writing.

```
puts "What is your birthday? (dd.mm.yyyy)"
user_input = gets.chomp

user_array = user_input.split(".")
uyyyy = user_array[2]
umm = user_array[1]
udd = user_array[0]

y = Time.now.year
m = Time.now.month
d = Time.now.day

require 'Date'
a = Date.new(y.to_i, m.to_i, d.to_i) - Date.new(uyyyy.to_i, umm.to_i, udd.to_i,)
sec = (a * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i

if a < 0
  puts "You are born in the future!"
  puts "You will be born in #{a} days"
else
  puts "Your year is #{uyyyy}! Your month is #{umm}! Your day is #{udd}!"
  puts "Todays year is #{y}! Todays month is #{m}! Todays day is #{d}!"
  puts "You are #{a.to_int/365} years, #{m} month and #{d} days old"    
  puts "You are #{sec} seconds old!"
end
```

Comment: You could use a simple regex. `/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/` should do the trick, I imagine.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You forgot `\A` and `\z`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look "regex" up to try and understand and learn it better. If you have any other suggestions on what to read or learn let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
while true
  puts "What is your birthday? (dd.mm.yyyy)"
  user_input = gets.chomp
  break if user_input =~ /\A\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\z/
end
udd, umm, uyyyy = user_input.split(".")
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look "regex" up to try and understand and learn it better. If you have any other suggestions on what to read or learn let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
require 'date'
while true do
    print "Enter bithday:"
    date_string = gets.chomp
    begin   
        date = Date.strptime(date_string, "%d.%m.%Y")
        print "Your bithday: #{date}"
        break
    rescue 
        puts "You enter incorrect date"
    end
end
```

Comment: Use `loop do` instead of `while true do`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That is simpler, but slower.

Comment: @sawa, I think speed in this script isn't important

Comment: @sawa: performance difference is irrelevant here. The bottleneck is user entering input.